# How to integrate Tomahawk in Glassfish v3?

Tags: jsf, glassfish, tomahawk

Can Tomahawk libs be added to one project or is it necessary to add libs into Glassfish libs folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can be added per project and do not have to be included in the global lib directory.